Cannot connect to node with jconsole after enabling SSL on JMX
I am using Cassandra 4 and have enabled SSL.
To connect to JMX, I added the following options in the cassandra-env.sh and started Cassandra
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=false"

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/home/murali/cassandra/cassandra4.0.13/conf/certs/keystore.cass4"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=cassandra"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/home/murali/cassandra/cassandra4.0.13/conf/certs/cassandra4.client.truststore.jks"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=cassandra"

#JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2"
#JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.cipher.suites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"

Tried connecting with JConsole as below,
$ jconsole -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=certs/keystore.cass4
  -J-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=cassandra 
  -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=certs/cassandra4.client.truststore.jks
  -J-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=cassandra

But it was failed to connect with JMX SSL.
And tried to connect with java code using javax.rmi package, and it was thrown below error.
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException \[Root exception is java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table\]

Note: used jdk 8 and 11 for jConsole and java, but error was same.
Please let us know your suggestions for successfully connecting to JMX and viewing Cassandra metrics.

Don't use quote format for code and errors. Use [code block] format.

Why are selecting that specific cipher suite?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Without (1) the full error message, and (2) the full stack trace, it is impossible to know the cause of the failure but usually it is at least one (or more) of the following:

the keystore is invalid
the keystore password is invalid
the truststore is invalid
the truststore password is invalid

One other thing to note is that it's likely you're connecting with jconsole remotely. By default, remote JMX connections are disabled for security reasons because it makes the node vulnerable to attacks so JMX is only accessible on localhost.
To enable JMX remote access, you need to uncomment the following line in cassandra-env.sh:
# JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public name>"

You need to configure it with an IP address that is accessible from the machine where you run jconsole. Then immediately after that line add this:
LOCAL_JMX=no

Note that you will need to restart Cassandra for the changes in cassandra-env.sh to take effect. Cheers!
